# ajax jquery page scroll is repeating results

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, jquery

i have created auto scroll for my website but i am getting repeated results something like this.if just consider the row no it is giving output like this

100
99
100
99
98
100
99
98
97

here is my javascript and php code
first page displays the message from database so i am taking that message id and making one ajax request .here is javascript which is on the same page as first message.

```
  <script>
   function getDocHeight() {
   var D = document;
  return Math.max(
  Math.max(D.body.scrollHeight, D.documentElement.scrollHeight),
  Math.max(D.body.offsetHeight, D.documentElement.offsetHeight),
   Math.max(D.body.clientHeight, D.documentElement.clientHeight)
      );
 }  
 $(window).scroll(function() {
  if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height()   == getDocHeight()) {

  $("#imgtag1").html("<img src="http://static.way2enjoy.com/files/loading.gif" />                         Loading");
    $.post("'.uhome().'/index.php?p=jquery/morethread/'.$nextb.'",
     function(data){
    $("#imgtag1").before(data);
   if (data) {
     $("#imgtag1").show();
    }
     $("#imgtag1").html("");
      },"html"
     );

      }
      });
      </script>
```

here is my morethread code

```
    $c=explode("/",$_SERVER[ 'REQUEST_URI' ]);  $city1=end($c); 

  $res = sql_query("select * from tableA where id='{$city1}'");
    $row67 = sql_fetch_array($res);
     $nextbtn=$row67['id']-1;
 echo '<script>
  function getDocHeight() {
 var D = document;
  return Math.max(
 Math.max(D.body.scrollHeight, D.documentElement.scrollHeight),
 Math.max(D.body.offsetHeight, D.documentElement.offsetHeight),
  Math.max(D.body.clientHeight, D.documentElement.clientHeight)
   );
  } 
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height()  == getDocHeight()) {

 $("#imgtag1").html("<img src=\"http://static.way2enjoy.com/files/loading.gif\" />               Loading");
     $.post("'.uhome().'/index.php?p=jquery/morethread/'.$nextbtn.'",
      function(data){
      $("#imgtag1").before(data);
   if (data) {
     $("#imgtag1").show();
    }
     $("#imgtag1").html("");
    },"html"
     );

    }
      });
      </script>';
      echo '<br></br>';
      echo nl2br(decode_bb(h($row67['id'])));
   echo '<br></br>';

         echo '<b>=============================================</b>';
       echo '<br></br>';

        echo nl2br(decode_bb(h($row67['message'])));
        echo '<br></br>';
       echo '<b>=============================================</b>';

        echo '<br></br>';
```

here is my live page where i am doing mistake .

```
         http://way2enjoy.com/forums/viewthread/149498/
```

Comment: _Do_ not _echo_ JavaScript codes, error-prone, hard to maintain.

Comment: @undefined got it remember in future

Comment: PHP + MySQL + HTML + javascript (+ jQuery) all mixed together, I was truly expecting to see some CSS in there also. Read something about [Separation of Concerns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns#HTML.2C_CSS.2C_JavaScript) to make your code cleaner and easier to mantain/debug.